# Parse String with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, parsing

I'm getting a report for users. The 'membership of' is a string with all the groups per user between double quotes.
I need to place \ between each group. Now I have:

```
"GROUP1""GROUP2""GROUP3"
```

And I need:

```
"GROUP1"\"GROUP2"\"GROUP3"
```

Right now my code is:

```
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    $Comp = $server
    if (test-connection -computername $Comp -count 1 -quiet) {
        ([ADSI]"WinNT://$comp").Children | ?{$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'} | %{
            $groups = $_.Groups() | %{$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}
            $_ | Select @{n='Server';e={$comp}},
                @{n='DistingishedName';e={$_.AdsPath}},
                @{n='Nombre';e={$_.FullName}},
                @{n='Departamento';e={$_.Department}},
                @{n='Email';e={$_.EmailAddress}},
                @{n='Active';e={if ($_.PasswordAge -like 0) {$false} else {$true}}},
                @{n='PasswordExpired';e={if ($_.PasswordExpired) {$true} else {$false}}},
                @{n='LastLogin';e={$_.LastLogin}},
                @{n='Description';e={$_.Description}},
                @{n='Groups';e={$Groups -join '"'}}
        } | Export-Csv  $ReportFile -Delimiter ';' -Force -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation -Append
    } else {
        Write-Warning "Server '$Comp' is Unreachable hence Could not fetch data"  3>>  $LogFile
    }
}
```

Comment: `Export-Csv` puts all exported fields in double quotes. Nested double quotes in a field are escaped by doubling them. Why do you think you need to join the group names with a double quote in the first place? Use a delimiter that doesn't interfere with CSV syntax.

Comment: I prefer to use other delimiter, but my boss says that he wants the output like: "GROUP1"\"GROUP2"\"GROUP3"
For me its ok with:
"GROUP1\GROUP2\GROUP3"
Maybe my boss is a troll? xD

Comment: Assuming that your boss wants the group name format after importing the CSV somehwere `'"{0}"' -f ($Groups -join '"\"')` should produce the desired results.

Comment: The output is:
"""GROUP1""\""GROUP2""\""GROUP3""\""GROUP4"""

Comment: Of course it is. Now try `Import-Csv your_output.csv`.

Comment: I've added Import-Csv my_output.csv at the end of the script and yes, there is the good output but on the screen. 
Now I have to redirect the output to the csv... I think I should handle on my own now... :S 
THANKS A LOT!

Comment: No, you don't have to redirect that output to a CSV, b/c your boss will most likely IMPORT THE CSV somewhere, and will thus NEED THE ORIGINAL CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `-join '"\"'` instead of `-join '"'`

Comment: I tried and:
"GROUP1""\""GROUP2""\""GROUP3""\""GROUP4"
There are two pairs of double quotes now...

Comment: so maybe you just need `'\'` however there could be a reason why there were two double quotes, because inside a csv field quotes are used as a delimiter and a double quote is escaped with a double quote are you sure you need `"\"` because csv will be not valid any more

Comment: Then the output is now:
"GROUP1\GROUP2\GROUP3"